# Why should we use system.assert in test class even after enough code coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test, assertexception

How to use system.assert in the below test class?

```
@isTest
public class a_Call_Objective_Trigger_Handler_Test{ 
    testMethod static void CallObjectiveTest(){ 

        RecordType Callrt = [SELECT ID,DEVELOPERNAME FROM Recordtype where and name = 'Standard'];  
        RecordType ParentProdrt = [SELECT ID,DEVELOPERNAME FROM Recordtype where  and name ='Brand'];
        RecordType ChildProdrt = [SELECT ID,DEVELOPERNAME FROM Recordtype where and name ='Detail'];  

        Account acc = new Account(LastName='Institution1',
                                  RecordtypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('MP (Medical Professional)').getRecordTypeId());
        insert acc;
        Address__c add = new Address__c(Name = 'Testing address',City__c = 'Roma');
        insert add;
       AccountAddress__c accAdd = new AccountAddress__c(Address__c = add.id,Account__c = acc.id,a_IsPrimary__c = true,a_SAP_ID__c = '12345',a_Ship_To__c = true);
        insert accAdd;

        a_AccountTerritoryFields__c  addATF = new a_AccountTerritoryFields__c (a_PreferredAddress__c = accAdd.id , a_Territory__c ='SR01',a_Account__c = acc.id); 
        addATF.a_Next_Call_Objective__c = 'Place P.O.S. materials';
        insert addATF;

        //create test data for Products

        a_Product__c parentprod = new a_Product__c();

        parentprod.Name = 'Parent product';
        parentprod.a_IsActive__c= true;
        parentprod.RecordTypeId= ParentProdrt.Id;
        INSERT parentprod;

        a_Product__c childprod = new a_Product__c();
        childprod.Name = 'Detail product';
        childprod.a_IsActive__c= true;
        childprod.RecordTypeId= ChildProdrt.Id;
        childprod.a_ParentProduct__c = parentprod.Id;
        INSERT childprod;

        //Create submit Call record
        a_Call__c newCall = new a_Call__c();
        newCall.a_Account__c = acc.Id;
        newCall.a_Location__c= accAdd.Id;
        newCall.a_Date__c = System.today();
        newCall.a_CallDateTime__c = System.now();
        newCall.Next_Call_Objective_Multipicklist__c= 'Place P.O.S. materials';
        newCall.a_DurationPicklist__c = '15';
        newCall.a_Channel__c='Face To Face';
        newCall.a_Status__c = 'Submitted';
        newCall.a_Territory__c = 'SR01'; 
        newcall.a_Call_Type__c = 'Sell Out'; 
        newCall.RecordTypeId = Callrt.id;
        insert newCall;

        //Create call detail
        a_CallDetail__c DetailCall = new a_CallDetail__c();
        DetailCall.a_Account__c = acc.ID;
        DetailCall.a_Call__c = newCall.ID;
        DetailCall.a_Product__c = childprod.ID; 
        insert DetailCall;

        //Create planned call record
        a_Call__c newCallPlanned = new a_Call__c();
        newCallPlanned.a_Account__c = acc.Id;
        newCallPlanned.a_Location__c= accAdd.Id;
        newCallPlanned.a_Date__c = System.today();
        newCallPlanned.a_CallDateTime__c = System.now();
        newCallPlanned.a_DurationPicklist__c = '15';
        newCallPlanned.a_Channel__c='Face To Face';
        newCallPlanned.a_Status__c = 'Draft';
        newCallPlanned.a_Territory__c = 'SR01'; 
        newCallPlanned.a_Call_Type__c = 'Sell Out'; 
        newCallPlanned.RecordTypeId = Callrt.id;

        test.startTest();
        insert newCallPlanned;
        update addATF;
        test.stopTest();

        //Create Call objective for the planned call.

        a_Call_Objectives__c CallObjective = new a_Call_Objectives__c();
        CallObjective.Call__c = newCallPlanned.id;
        CallObjective.Objective__c = 'Place P.O.S. materials';
        CallObjective.Completed__c = False;
        insert CallObjective;                  
    }        
}
```

Comment: We use assert to check if the code we have written is giving expected output. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_example.htm) it is explained in detail.

Comment: Ok then we have to use too many system.asserts in above class as there are many mandatory fields are there. Do we need to write asserts for each field value for above class?

Comment: Ideally, we use it to check the output, not the mandatory fields. Like, let's say if you have calculated some field using the trigger, we check the value of that field with the expected outcome for the inputs we provide in the test class.

Comment: in that case we no need to write asserts for above class. is it?

Comment: assert if the record is inserted successfully

Comment: please see the entries in [canonical-qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) which is a terrific resource on unit testing best practices

Answer (score 0):

Basically we are writing System.Assert to check the expected behaviour of the code. Test class covers because of the date we are creating as per the code but it's not guarantee you the expected outcome. For that reason we must need to include the System.Assert statement for each method at least one. Thanks !